# Formula and fractions in lyx

Tags: lyx

I want to write to following formulas in lyx: Ic  = (Number of new cases in D)/P0 and this one TBM  =(Total number of all-cause deaths in a given region over a specified period)/(Estimated total exposed population of the same region during the same period). can someone help me please

Comment: Can you add more details. What did you try and why isn't it working?

Comment: I'm new to lyx and I don'tt know how to create such formulas

Comment: I tried insert - Math - inline formula - then select Fractions - I've tris all of them standard to display binomial but none lof them allowed me to write a phrase in the numerator or the denumerator.

Comment: When you are in math mode, type `\text` and then space. Then start typing normal text. Or try "ctrl + M" (when you are already inside math mode). Does that work? For more information, please read Help > Math. Inserting text is discussed there.

Comment: Thank you so much it did work. can you please reply to the question so I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in math mode, type \text and then space. Then start typing normal text. Or try "ctrl + M" (when you are already inside math mode). For more information, please read Help > Math. Inserting text is discussed there.